# Way to move a large image smoothly?

Tags: jquery, setinterval, watch, smoothing, requestanimationframe

I have a very wide image of a snowy scene with some trees, and an element on top of it of a snowball. The game is to make the snowball jump over the trees. So, I have the image moving to the left as a sort of side scroller, but no matter what I try, it's very laggy. I have a set of if clauses to check to see if the ball has collided with a tree, and I've tried using setInterval, watch.js and requestAnimationFrame.js without much luck.

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing

```js
$('#StartScroller').click(function() {
      sideScroller.css('left', '-10000px');
      snowball.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(12000deg)',
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '100px'
      });
```

```js
$('sideScroller').watch('left', function(){
 //1
 if(
 (sideScroller.position().left < -960 
 && sideScroller.position().left > -1200 + mobileDelay)
 && (snowball.css('bottom') == '75px')
 ){hitTree()}
```

Anyone know of an alternative that will make it more smooth? It's a bit of an eye sore now.

Comment: Suggest for using translate3d or other 3d methods. Because 3d methods do not cause repaints and so no stutter/lag.

Comment: What cause the lag? The animation? Your collision logic snippet? Or both? I can imagine your collision snippet in interval is enough to make it lags

Comment: It appeared to be the animation. As soon as I used a transform instead of left positioning, it cleared up! I wouldn't be surprised if setInterval causes some problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a very simple solution: Instead of using left positioning to move the image, I used transform: translate. MUCH better. Still, I would love to hear any alternatives to using setInterval to monitor changes. Yoram mentioned a 3d translate. I tried the regular translate and translateX, but am not sure if I notice a difference.